# Programmatically change a certain font+size to a different font+size

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a ms-word document where Helvetica 13.5 is the main font for paragraphs.  Unfortunately, it's not tied to any particular pre-defined style in the document (the text was copied into the document from a website).  Additionally, you will see embedded in the paragraphs a few words italicized and some words which are 'Courier New'.

What I'd like to do is walk through the document looking for snippets of text that have a single font/size.  If that text is Helvetica 13.5, I would like to change it to Times New Roman 12.  I don't want to change the embedded courier new.  Italicized words should stay italicized (but their font should change if it's Helvetica/13.5)

Is there an "easy" way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 Sub Helv_to_TNR

 With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.Text = ""
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Font.Size = 13.5
.Replacement.Font.Size = 11
.Font.Name = "Helvetica"
.Replacement.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
end with

end sub
```

Comment: is this VBA?  how can this be applied  to a word doc _externally_ to the doc itself? I am in `macOS` so we're talking `bash` or `python` or something else that can manipulate the doc via an api

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this programmatically, but I know Word has the ability to Find and Replace based on Formatting. Here is how you do it:

- In your document for Windows do Ctrl-G, for Mac do Command-Option-G. This will pull up the Go To window.
- Select the Replace tab
- In the Replace tab you should see for Windows "More >>", for Mac a "v" (Down arrow). Hit that button, to pull up the extra functions.
- Now choose the format you are looking for by hitting the format button at the bottom.
- To choose the new format you want, select the "Replace with" text field and then do the same as the previous step. Your options should show up below the respective text field.
- When ready, hit Replace All

Note: keep the text fields empty if you want the replace to only match text based on formatting